# Angular 6 Viewbox? (Similar to WPF/Silverlight)

Tags: html, asp.net, angular, silverlight

I'm doing a re-write of a silverlight application and we decided to use Angular 6 (AKA Angular 2).

Within our silverlight app, we have the entire app encapsulated in a viewbox. This allows us to resize the window and everything on screen will scale with the window. Can anyone tell me if there is a way to achieve this with Angular?

Note: I've came across SVG elements that can be used with angular and this supports a viewbox- But, it appears these are only for image rendering (Defining vectors and drawing primitive images) and you can't exactly put a button, and inputs inside of there.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You're probably looking for creating a response Single Page Application. You can use Bootstrap that is going to change the structure of your App for different device breakpoints.

Comment: If you were using ViewBox as the content host of the entire SL application then it means the layout wasn't made to be correctly responsive in the first place and there's probably a ton of hard set margins etc all over the place. There is no replacement for ViewBox in any HTML5/JS/Ang regards that I'm aware of but it would generally be bad practice to use like that anyway. Think of this as your chance to make things properly responsive using REM units, Media Queries, and fluid layouts provided by UI frameworks like Zurb Foundation or Bootstrap 4, etc. :)

Comment: Ah okay, Yeah I currently write single page applications using angular and bootstrap. This has been the goto web solution for the business I'm a part of. The benefit of the silverlight app we've signed up to rewrite is that users can resize their window and everything remains in the same position (just scales accordingly in the current aspect ratio) - eliminating clipping and all that non-sense. This also lets users with bad eyes to just expand the browser window to give a "zoomed in" effect. I've wrote many "responsive" apps, just none that can produce the same effect with growable text- etc.

Comment: Extra in regards to the last comment: I'm also familiar with using @media tags to scale font-size depending on window size and other tricks of that nature. But even with all of those tricks, it doesn't get me the same result that a viewbox / viewport (whatever it is) would get me in silverlight. (Basically the same as the auto scaling feature an image does when resizing a browser window). But thanks for the insight! ^_^

Comment: Right, but luckily for those folks with the poor eyesight, the browser allows zooming on it's own, even in a PWA, and if you use calc units for fonts and spacing like REM in lieu of PX based layouts you should still have a nice way for them to get the content they need like text etc. However if the viewport is too crowded, that's when actual responsiveness should come into play and those built in media queries takeover to position things intuitively instead of giving them some huge panel to pan around in & zoom, even MS encourages that form of UX over the ViewBox method you describe.

Comment: Yeah I hear ya, Thanks for the tips. Oh boy- Don't get me started on MS and their suggestions. xD